# Some character disappear after decode base64 in golang

Tags: go, jwt, base64

I built simple program to generate Json Web Token (JWT), everything ran normally until I made a token verification to verify the JWT, the problem came after I decode base64 string to check the header token. Some part of the binary is disappear, whereas the string value is from encoded base64. Here my code and the result

```
package auth

import "encoding/base64"
import "crypto/sha256"
import "encoding/json"
import "strings"
import "crypto/hmac"
import "encoding/hex"
import "fmt"


type Header struct{
    Alg string
    Typ string
}

type Payload struct{
    id          int
    name        string
    userType    bool
    keepLogin   bool
}

var key string = "12345678" //temporary
var payloadJson Payload

func GenerateToken(alg string, typ string, payload []byte)(string, error){
    var headerEncoded, payloadEncoded, signature, mergedEncoded string
    header := Header{Alg: alg,Typ: typ}
    hmacDeclare := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(key))


    headerJson, errHeader := json.Marshal(header)//struct -> byte
    if errHeader != nil{
        return "",errHeader
    }
    
    headerEncoded = encodeBase64(headerJson)//byte -> string
    payloadEncoded = encodeBase64(payload)//byte -> string
    mergedEncoded = headerEncoded+"."+payloadEncoded
    if alg=="SHA256"{
        hmacDeclare.Write([]byte(mergedEncoded))
        signature = hex.EncodeToString(hmacDeclare.Sum(nil))
    }

    finalToken := headerEncoded+"."+payloadEncoded+"."+signature
    
    //JUST SAMPLE TO TEST JWT RESULT
    fmt.Println("Before encode (byte) => ", headerJson)
    fmt.Println("Before encode (string) => ", string(headerJson))
    fmt.Println("After encode (base64/string) => ", headerEncoded)
    checkDecode,_ := decodeBase64(headerEncoded)//string -> byte
    fmt.Println("After decode (byte) => ", checkDecode)
    fmt.Println("After decode (string) => ", string(checkDecode))
    // _, _ = VerifyToken(finalToken)
    return finalToken, nil
}

func encodeBase64(data []byte) string {
    formatString := strings.TrimRight(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data),"=")
    return formatString
}

func decodeBase64(data string)([]byte, error){
    result, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
    if err != nil{
        return result, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

and here the result

```
Before encode (byte) =>  [123 34 65 108 103 34 58 34 83 72 65 50 53 54 34 44 34 84 121 112 34 58 34 74 87 84 34 125]
Before encode (string) =>  {"Alg":"SHA256","Typ":"JWT"}
After encode (base64/string) =>  eyJBbGciOiJTSEEyNTYiLCJUeXAiOiJKV1QifQ
After decode (byte) =>  [123 34 65 108 103 34 58 34 83 72 65 50 53 54 34 44 34 84 121 112 34 58 34 74 87 84 34]
After decode (string) =>  {"Alg":"SHA256","Typ":"JWT"
```

[image: Screenshoot from the result]

Does anyone have same issue? I've tried browsing for it but found no same issue

Comment: Why are you ignoring the error from decodeBase64?

Comment: The error from decodeBase64 is this "illegal base64 data at input byte 36". Is = cause error decoding? Cause I try to decode it using online base64 decoder run normally and give right string result

Comment: JWT uses Base64Url encoding which has no trailing '='.

Comment: It's mean I should give "=" at the last of the string right? But some time I found there are more than 1 "=" sign

Comment: the number of padding '=' can be 0, 1 or 2, the resulting string must have a length which is a multiple of 4. But you should check if the base64 decoder can decode Base64Url, then you don't need to modify the string.

Comment: I just add "var RawStdEncoding = base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(-1)" to give no padding after encode base64 afer read documentation, now the code runs smoothly. Thanks for help

Comment: Issue solved, just add "var RawStdEncoding = base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(-1)" to avoid padding, -1 stands for "No Padding" then use "RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)" and "RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(data)" to encode and decode

Comment: RawStdEncoding [is predefined in the standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#pkg-variables). However, as others have pointed out JWT uses URL encoding (i.e. use base64.RawURLEncoding). You should seriously consider using a reputable library for dealing with JWT. You already made the mistake of choosing the wrong encoding and the verification is deceptively complicated. [People get it wrong all the time.](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/).

Comment: Okay thank you, I will learn more detail about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the padding don't trim it, instead use [`WithPadding`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64@go1.17.5#Encoding.WithPadding) and pass in [`NoPadding`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64@go1.17.5#NoPadding).

```golang
func encodeBase64(data []byte) string {
    e := base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding)
    return e.EncodeToString(data)
}

func decodeBase64(data string) ([]byte, error) {
    e := base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding)
    result, err := e.DecodeString(data)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/bs6Wte-wHeD

Comment: Yes, I just add this "var RawStdEncoding = base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(-1)" after read documentation. Now the decoded string return valid json string. Thank you, this comment also helping me